# mosso alternative

Tags: hosting

Was using Mosso and loving it until they just changed there permissions, now reflection is not allowed - WTF - sweet, just as I migrated a bunch of stuff they change their setup.

anyone have good experience with a similar company using .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what reflections is...

I haven't actually tried them but I've heard of [GoGrid](http://www.gogrid.com) and Amazon EC2.

Best of luck to you.

Comment: I meant Reflection, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [SiteCloud](http://www.sitecloud.com), they are running a cPanel-based cloud hosting platform. Might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection actually is allowed on Mosso. They're not using full medium trust which is extremely restrictive, but medium trust with the following permissions added back:

- WebPermission Unrestricted="true"
- OleDbPermission Unrestricted="true"
- OdbcPermission Unrestricted="true"
- SocketPermission Unrestricted="true"
- ConfigurationPermission
  Unrestricted="true"
- ReflectionPermission
  Unrestricted="true"

Most things work as long as you add the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute. I've outlined more details on my blog here: [How to use iBatis/NHibernate in medium trust/partial trust environments like Mosso](http://programcsharp.com/blog/archive/2009/08/19/ibatis-nhibernate-mosso-medium-trust-partial-trust-environments.aspx)